# filter a column in excel to specific word using java code

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an Excel file which needs filtering on a specific column.

```java
String fileName = "filepath";
String cellContent = "Automation";
int rownr = 0;
int colnr = 0; //column from which you need data to store in array list
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
List filteredCol = new ArrayList();
filteredCol = findRow(sheet, cellContent);
if (filteredCol != null) {
    for (Iterator iter = filteredCol.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
}

private static List findRow(HSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent) {
    List filter=new ArrayList();
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)) {
                    //System.out.println("Row numbers are"+row.getRowNum());
                    int rownumber=row.getRowNum();
                    //return row.getRowNum();
                    XSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(rownumber);
                    XSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(0);
                    filter.add(cell1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return filter;
}
```

I am getting number format exception on  this codeline:
"cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)"

Comment: Not fully familiar with POI, but does it make sense to be looking for an HSSFRow and HSSFColumn in an XSSFSheet?

Comment: Ohh, my bad, it is supposed to be XSSFRow and XSSFColumn. 
Yet the same Exception occurs

Comment: getRichStringCellValue() only works on a cells that have text in them - numeric values will lead to issues - this in the javadoc - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getRichStringCellValue--

Comment: There a few ways to handle getting values from cells that are safe - you could check cell.getCellType() and use switch or if to call the right getter for that type of cell - I find it is easier to create a DataFormatter instance and use this method - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-